# export records from a table by modifying without double quotes for the numeric columns from the table in db2(udb)

Tags: db2, export, db2-luw

I am trying to remove the double quotes for the numeric columns using export command by using replace function but it wont worked out, below is the query I used in Linux environment,

```
EXPORT TO '/Staging/ebi/src/CLP/legal_bill_charge_adjustment11.csv' OF DEL 
MESSAGES '/Staging/ebi/src/CLP/legal_bill_charge_adjustment11.log' 
select
CLIENT_ID,
CLIENT_DIVISION_ID,
CLIENT_OFFICE_ID,
MATTER_ID,
LEGAL_BILL_CHARGE_ADJ_ID,
LEGAL_BILL_CHARGE_ID,
ADJUSTMENT_DT,
replace ( ORIGINAL_ADJUSTMENT_AMT,""),
replace (CURRENT_ADJUSTMENT_AMT,""),
replace (SYSTEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMT,""),
replace (CLIENT_ADJUSTMENT_AMT,""),
replace (DELETED_ADJUSTMENT,""),
FLAGGED_AMOUNT,
ADJUSTMENT_USER,
STATUS_DESC,
ADJUSTMENT_COMMENT,
WF_TASK_NAME,
WF_TASK_DESC from CLP.legal_bill_charge_adjustment1;
```

If anyone suggest me the exact db2 query it would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is some data you have and how would it look like after being exported?

Comment: Am having data like

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I am having data like "1144025","1144026","1144037","18290966","17345288","925940","Unknown","Expense" After data being exported it should be look like 1144025,1144026,1144037,18290966,17345288,925940,"Unknown","Expense" without double quotes enclosed for numeric columns.

Comment: edit the question, include the data and their data type

Comment: You can try the `modified by nochardel` option, but that will strip delimiters from all columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I need only the numeric columns double quotes to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Export will not have quotes around numeric data types. You have not provided any data type information so I suppose your numeric content may be stored in a CHAR/VARCHAR column.
Try casting the columns to numeric data types in the export SQL statement.

i.e.

```
SELECT cast(Textcol as integer) as colname
```

..

Comment: Thanks..But i dont want to change column datatype,

 i have five columns as

name,age,address,salary,department

name -->varchar(20)

age->integer

address->varchar(200)

salary-->decimal(23,6)

department-->varchar(50)

Comment: I am havig data to load the table in a csv file below,

"alvin","45","xyz street petaluma, north america","200000.00","xyz"

db2 is taking numeric value enclosed with the double as string

I want the data to be look like

"alvin",45,"xyz street petaluma north america",200000.00,"xyz"

Is there any command to load the data without double quotes for numric columns into 
the table.

please suggest any solution for the above issue would be very helpfull for me.

Comment: This is confusing - in your original question you alk aout exporting (in Db2 exporting means moving data from the database to a file) and now your comment is that you have got a file and that you want to load it into the database...

Comment: Yes..Actually my issue is to load the CSV file into a table without double quotes for only numeric columns..To remove the double quotes for numeric columns I have created the same dummy table and make numeric columns as varchar and I have loaded the data..

Comment: then I tried to export the data from the table by replacing double quotes.